# Recurring Payment in Kentico with Paypal payment option

Tags: kentico

What is the best way to implement the recurring payment in Kentico with Paypal as payment option? Is there any built-in webparts/modules available or do we need to customize the payment option.

I am using Kentico 10.

Answer (score 1):

Your best approach is to create your own custom Paypal payment gateway and implementing the features you want.  I did this with Authorize.NEt about a year or so ago without issue.  The key is to build the payment gateway as if it doesn't even exist in Kentico.